# this version of path/to/g++.exe is not compatible with the windows version you are running

Tags: c++, codeblocks, 32-bit, mingw-w64

I downloaded Code::blocks to learn C++ on and I chose the Min-GW compiler download choice and installed Code::blocks and added compiler path to the environment variables but when I run `g++ --version` in the command it gives me the error above.

and I manually Added the compiler path in Code::Blocks app but still gives `Couldn't Find the compiler path`

I have windows 10 32-bit and this is the version I downloaded

`https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/20.03/Windows/32bit/codeblocks-20.03mingw-32bit-setup.exe/download`

Note: I tried the other download source Foss-HUB but the same thing

Comment: This version of your install has a compiler located in the subdirectory under the directory of codeblocks, e.g. c:\program file\codeblocks\MingGw. With this version, it should automatic set the default compile. Why do you have to add the path of compiler?

Comment: In codeblocks, look into the global compiler settings > toolchain executables. There shall show the directory of the MinGW: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW. if not, using the select directory button (...) to select the directory of MinGw.

Comment: that was the main reason I tried to add the path of the compiler because when I added the path of the compiler in Code::Blocks settings it gave me error (Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path) and I thought that path might work but it didn't

Comment: now I did what u said again and removed the path for the environment and made sure I added the path in Code::Blocks settings still the same

Comment: Please check the directory c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin to check if the executable files are there?

Comment: ok I checked this and i personally do not know how many files should be there but I found like 59 exe files and 6 (.dll) files there

Comment: That looks ok. I hadn't encounter problems like this with codeblocks. Did you tried the version 13.12?

Comment: No just the 20.03 but I actually may try other versions now

Comment: but I think version 13.12 is for mac not windows

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/

Comment: Yeah this version worked fine thank you I think Its about the version 20.03

Comment: Great. The 32-bit in version 20.03 may be 64-bit compiler and IDE, but provides extra compatible to build 32-bit appplications. Version 13.12 is very stable. I had worked with it for many years. It is true 32-bit with older MinGW compiler.

Comment: It reminded me that the 32-bit of MinGW of version 20.03 is located at c:\program Files\codeblocks\x86_64-w64-mingw32. You may give it (20.03) one more try. Direct the toolchain to that directory.

Comment: Actually it's located at C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32 
but however unfortunately it didn't work either